# Flask SqlAlchemy 2 table join : how to retrieve rows with both objects

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, flask

I have the following join :

```
user = User.query.join(UserEmail).filter_by(address = js['email'].lower()).first()
```

It works, but I also want the UserEmail in the result row

How would I achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
session.query(User, UserEmail).join(UserEmail).filter(...)
```

The result is a tuple of `(User, UserEmail)`